# Exposing form input when previous is selected or filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This will most likely need to involve javascript, which I know almost nothing about so please bear with me.

I would like to have a regular form, say styled with bootstrap. But I don't want to display the all the fields at once when the page is loaded. Instead I would like to display the first field and continue to display the following fields as the previous fields are focused or have content in them.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="website">Website</label>
        <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

In this example only "Name" would show up, when the page loads, then when it is focused then the "Email" field would show up.

Any ideas would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JQuery to remove a `hidden` class on input focus.

Run the code snippet or check out the **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/vJKXbv)**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").focus(function() {
    $(this).parent(".form-group").next().removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group hidden">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group hidden">
    <label for="website">Website</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group hidden">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect, I will be combining some ideas from both submissions. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Just hide all elements in the form except for the first one, listen for changes on the form and display the next element relating to the last changed element (the `event.target`).

Example (which is definitley improvable):

```js
$(".form-group:not(:first-child)").hide();
$("form").on("change keypress paste", function (event) {
    $(event.target).parent().next().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="website">Website</label>
        <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I would add `focus` event to the `.on()` and use bootstrap `hidden` class instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`. So, `.addClass('hidden')` and `.removeClass('hidden')`

Comment: I particularly like that the next field doesn't show up until there is text in the input fields, much appreciated!